# Swift Eureka Hide Section On Change

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, eureka-forms

I am using the Eureka Swift form library found [here](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka).

I have a textfield and whenever you start typing in it, I would like the other sections of the form to be hidden. I started out by just trying to hide 1 section but nothing happens when I start typing in the field. My code is as follows:

```
  form  +++ Section("Device Search")

        <<< IntRow()
            {
                $0.title = "Asset Tag"
                $0.placeholder = "Enter Asset Tag #"
            }

            .onChange { row in

              self.form.sectionBy(tag: "iOS Version")?.hidden = true
        }

        +++ Section("iOS Version")


        for version in countArray
        {

            form.last! <<< CheckRow()
                {
                    $0.title = version
                    $0.tag = $0.title


            }
        }
```

Also, is there a way to use an IntRow but remove the formatter for just the row?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**About your second question** *is there a way to use an IntRow but remove the formatter for just the row?*

Add this line `$0.formatter = nil` just below this one `$0.placeholder = "Enter Asset Tag #"`

**Your first question**, how hide a `section` in `EurekaForm`, first of all your section initialisation is not what you think it is, I will explain myself, you think that you are initalizating your section with tag, but in section definition none of init methods use `tag` as parameter so to get the correct section you need change your section initialization for this one

```
        +++ Section("iOS Version"){ //"iOS Version" is actually the header text"
            $0.tag = "test"  //this is the tag
        }
```

**after that you need to modify this**

```
.onChange { row in

              self.form.sectionBy(tag: "iOS Version")?.hidden = true
        }
```

**by this one**

```
 .onChange { row in
                if let section = self.form.sectionBy(tag: "test")
                {
                    section.hidden = true 
                    section.evaluateHidden()   //you are missing calling this method
                }
        }
```

After that your header named "iOS Version" is hidden after you write any number on your `IntRow`

## Full Code

```
form  +++ Section("Device Search")
            
            <<< IntRow()
                {
                    $0.title = "Asset Tag"
                    $0.placeholder = "Enter Asset Tag #"
                    $0.formatter = nil
                }
                
                .onChange { row in
                    if let section = self.form.sectionBy(tag: "test")
                    {
                        section.hidden = true
                        section.evaluateHidden()
                    }
            }
            
            +++ Section("iOS Version"){
                $0.tag = "test"
        }
        
        for version in countArray
        {
            form.last! <<< CheckRow()
                {
                    $0.title = version
                    $0.tag = $0.title
            }
        }
```